# Do these functions exist?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, examples-counterexamples

I created this question, but, I do not know the answer:

> Is there a function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that for every interval $I \subseteq \mathbb R$ we have $f(I)=\mathbb R$?

It seems to me that existence of such a function would violate almost everything that I know about analysis, but, on the other hand, it would be awesome if there is at least one such $f$, because it is known that there are many "pathological" examples in analysis. Also, many here are skilled in analysis more than I am, so I can expect an answer, curious about what it will turn to be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's for instance [Conway's base-$13$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function).

Comment: Are there any other examples? Or how to obtain them? I thought that it will be very hard to find such a function.